# why angular emits multiple time socket events?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

I read lots of solution from stackoverflow and having almost same answer but still the issue of "socket io emit multiple time events in client side angluarjs" I really don't understand.

Here I can emit deletPhoto event to delete photo and deletePhotoResponse event to update photo counter, but deletePhotoResponse trigger double time then previous on each event call.

Can anyone guide me?

HzSocket.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module("App")
        .factory("HzSocket", ['$rootScope', '$cookies', '$location', 'HzServices',
            function ($rootScope, $cookies, $location, HzServices) {
                var socket = io.connect(HzServices.getAppUrl(), {
                    query: 'token=' + $cookies.get("hz-token")
                });
                return {
                    on: function (eventName, callback) {
                        socket.on(eventName, function () {
                            var args = arguments;
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                callback.apply(socket, args);
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                            var args = arguments;
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                if (callback) {
                                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    },
                    removeAllListeners: function (eventName) {
                        socket.removeAllListeners(eventName, function () {
                            var args = arguments;
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                callback.apply(socket, args);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
        ]);
}());
```

PhotoCtrl.js

```
(function () {

    'use strict';
    function PhotoCtrl($rootScope, $scope, HzSocket) {
        $scope.deletePhoto = function (photo, album, photoIndex, flag) {       
                HzSocket.emit("deletePhoto", data);
                HzSocket.on("deletePhotoResponse", function (data) {
                });
                $scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
                    //HzSocket.removeAllListeners(this);
                    HzSocket.removeAllListeners('deletePhotoResponse');
                });               
            }
        };
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
            HzSocket.removeAllListeners(event);
        });
    }
    angular
            .module("App")
            .controller('PhotoCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'HzSocket', PhotoCtrl]);
}());
```

Comment: I think your are missing an array in module definition, should be `angular.module("App", [])`

Comment: @Adrian: I am not missing anything in my actual code but due to typo it may mistake.. but original issue is that in angularjs event emits multiple time.. Thank you for guildeline.